# computer needs ipconfig release and renew to get on network

Tags: networking

There is one laptop in a small office, of mostly wired computers (*with some other laptops though*).

This laptop is connected via wifi. internet works fine, however I cannot get on the network at all, even typing in the network location in windows explorer just pops up an error and says "Diagnose..." etc.

Until I do an `ipconfig /release` & `ipconfig /renew`

Right after doing that I am on the network and can access all the other computers.

This happens consistently.

What can I check that could be causing this?

Comment: is your network dhcp enabled? sounds like there is an ip address conflict.

Comment: @Sackling Are you getting a valid IP when this happens ? Are you able to ping ?

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ yes the network is DHCP enabled.

Comment: Tell us the **exact** error messages so we can help you. Also, what OS are you using and how are the network settings configured (static or dynamic)?

Comment: check if there is any device on your network that manually configured to receive a specific ip address.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I am pretty sure it is a valid IP. And I believe when I release/renew I am getting the same DHCP address. Who should I try pinging? Another location on the network or a website?

Comment: How about other values. Same default gateway? Same netmask? No changes between IPv6 and IPv4 (e.g. on an IPv6 access to the internet but IPv4 only internal hosts or vice versa, with one changing), ....